# How to get all ranks in MPI to do a send a value to rank 0 which then does a blocking receive on all of them?

Tags: c, multithreading, mpi, openmpi, message-passing

Say I have n processes:

They do a calculation, and then send the result to rank 0. This is what I want to happen:

Rank 0 will **wait** till it has a result from all of the ranks and then **add them up**.

How do I do this? Also, I want to avoid the following:

For eg. 4 processes P0, P1, P2, P3,

```
P1 -> P0
P2 -> P0
P3 -> P0
```

In the meanwhile P1 has finished its calculation and so P1->P0 happens again.

**I want P0 to only make the addition for 3 processes in one cycle before doing it for the next one**.

Can someone suggest an MPI function to do this? I know about MPI_Gather but I'm not sure if its blocking

I've thought up of this:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int pross, rank,p_count = 0;
int count = 10;
MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&pross);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);

int * num = malloc((pross-1)*sizeof(int));

        if(rank !=0)
        {
            MPI_Send(&count,1,MPI_INT,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
        else
        {            
            MPI_Gather(&count, 1,MPI_INT,num, 1, MPI_INT, 0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            for(ii = 0; ii < pross-1;ii++ ){printf("\n NUM %d \n",num[ii]); p_count += num[ii]; }
}
MPI_Finalize();
}
```

I'm getting error:

```
  *** Process received signal ***
  Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
  Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
  Failing at address: (nil)
  [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11630)[0x7fb3e3bc3630]
  [ 1] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x90925)[0x7fb3e387b925]
  [ 2] /usr/lib/libopen-pal.so.13(+0x30177)[0x7fb3e3302177]
  [ 3] /usr/lib/libmpi.so.12(ompi_datatype_sndrcv+0x54c)[0x7fb3e3e1e3ec]
  [ 4] /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_tuned.so(ompi_coll_tuned_gather_intra_basic_linear+0x143)[0x7fb3d53d9063]
  [ 5] /usr/lib/libmpi.so.12(PMPI_Gather+0x1ba)[0x7fb3e3e29a3a]
  [ 6]  sosuks(+0xe83)[0x55ee72119e83]
  [ 7] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf1)[0x7fb3e380b3f1]
  [ 8]  sosuks(+0xb5a)[0x55ee72119b5a]
  *** End of error message ***
```

Also, I tried:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int pross, rank,p_count = 0;
int count = 10;
MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&pross);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);

int * num = malloc((pross-1)*sizeof(int));

        if(rank !=0)
        {
            MPI_Send(&count,1,MPI_INT,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
        else
        {            
            MPI_Gather(&count, 1,MPI_INT,num, 1, MPI_INT, 0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            for(ii = 0; ii < pross-1;ii++ ){printf("\n NUM %d \n",num[ii]); p_count += num[ii]; }
}
MPI_Finalize();
}
```

I'm getting error here:

```
  *** Process received signal ***
  Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
  Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
  Failing at address: 0x560600000002
  [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11630)[0x7fefc8c11630]
  [ 1] mdscisuks(+0xeac)[0x5606c1263eac]
  [ 2] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf1)[0x7fefc88593f1]
  [ 3] mdscisuks(+0xb4a)[0x5606c1263b4a]
  *** End of error message ***
```

For the second attempt, the thing to note here is that the send and recv were successful but **root could only receive 2 messages from ranks for some reason**. The segmentation fault seen was due to there being only two elements in num, I dont see why **num only receives twice**.

I'm calling the code as

```
mpiexec -n 6 ./sosuks
```

Can someone tell me a better / correct way to implement my idea ?

UPDATE:

Apart from the answer below I found the mistake in my implementation above which I wanted to share:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int pross, rank,p_count = 0;
int count = 10;
MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&pross);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
MPI_Status status;
int * num = malloc((pross-1)*sizeof(int));

        if(rank !=0)
        {
            MPI_Send(&count,1,MPI_INT,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
        else
        {
        int var,lick = 0;
        for(lick = 1; lick < pross; u++)
        {
        int fetihs;
        MPI_Recv(&fetihs,1,MPI_INT,lick,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);          

        var += fetihs;
        }
     // do things with var
}
MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: If you're adding up all the results, then you probably want `MPI_Reduce`, not `MPI_Gather`.

Comment: But would it follow the blocking procedure as I outlined in the question above? I'm trying to make the addition only after all the processes reach a certain point. In a way, I'm trying to "synchronise" results from all processes at that step.

Comment: Your description isn't very clear, but it sounds like you want a barrier for each round. Yes, there'll be a barrier (there's no logical way to do a reduction without one).

Comment: I'm new to this. What is a barrier?

Comment: A barrier is a point in execution which all processes must reach before any  of them is allowed to continue beyond the barrier.

Comment: @Sneftel What if I have a very important part of the code which I want all of the ranks to execute together, can I sandwich it between two MPI_Barriers() ? For eg. MPI_Barrier()   //  code  //  MPI_Barrier() ?

Comment: No. There's no such thing as "execute together" in MPI. I think you may misunderstand how to leverage it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, as Sneftel pointed out, you need `MPI_Reduce`. Also, you don't need explicit synchronization before the cycle completes.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int pross, rank, p_count, count = 10;

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &pross);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    int* num = malloc((pross-1)*sizeof(int));

    // master does not send data to itself.
    // only workers send data to master.

    for (int i=0; i<3; ++i)
    {
        // to prove that no further sync is needed.
        // you will get the same answer in each cycle.
        p_count = 0; 

        if (rank == 0)
        {
            // this has not effect since master uses p_count for both 
            // send and receive buffers due to MPI_IN_PLACE.
            count = 500;

            MPI_Reduce(MPI_IN_PLACE, &p_count, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
        else
        {
            // for slave p_count is irrelevant.
            MPI_Reduce(&count, NULL, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }

        if (rank == 0)
        {
            printf("p_count = %i\n", p_count);
        }

        // slaves send their data to master before the cycle completes.
        // no need for explicit sync such as MPI_Barrier.
        // MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD); // no need.
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

In the code above `count` in slaves are reduced to `p_count` in master. Note the `MPI_IN_PLACE` and two `MPI_Reduce` calls. You can get the same functionality by simply setting `count = 0` and calling `MPI_Reduce` by all ranks without `MPI_IN_PLACE`.

```
for (int i=0; i<3; ++i)
{
    p_count = 0;    
    if (rank == 0) count = 0;

    MPI_Reduce(&count, &p_count, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);           
}
```